# Water pipe coding exercise. How do I visualize solving this problem

Tags: javascript, arrays, path-finding

This is an online exercise that I am trying to understand the solution to.

The question is:

> Given the image below (a multidimensional array) the 0 values act as a
> pipe and the 1 values act as cement. I need to write code to determine
> if the "pipe" extends from the top of the first array(you can say this
> is an "opening" of a pipe) to the bottom of the last array.
>
> ```
> const arr = [
>     [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
>     [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
>     [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
>     [1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
>     [1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
> ]
> ```
>
> The code you write for the above array would output "true" because the
> 0 values form the following pattern (replace with the asterisk):
>
> ```
> const arr = [
>     [0, 0, 0, *, 1],
>     [0, 0, 1, *, *],
>     [0, 0, 0, 1, *],
>     [1, 1, 1, 1, *],
>     [1, 0, 1, 1, *],
> ]
> ```

In my head I visualize this problem as one where I would create a pointer to move through the arrays. If the rules only required the coder to work with a single 0 per array the problem would be easy to solve. Being that there are multiple dead ends is where my mind turns to mush. I assume there is an easier way to look at this problem that thinking in loops. I know that this can be mathemetized but I am not exactly a math person.

My remedial though process is to simply create a collection of functions such as:

```
checkSurroundingValues()
goForward()
goBackward()
goLeft()
goDOwn()
goUp()
```

etc , but doing it this way evolves into an over complicated mess. I figure there are a few tricks to visualize how to complete this problem. I want to understand "the trick" and thought process clearly.

**I feel like the way to go is to write code that follows each "zero" and effectively spawns off a new "crawler" to follow each trail but I have no idea how to write that. :)**

Answer (score 1):

> doing it this way evolves into an over complicated mess

It's more repetitive than you need, but not by that much.

First make a Set or array of indicies visited so far, eg `1_2` corresponds to having visited `arr[1][2]`. Make a recursive function that:

- Checks to see if the position being iterated over has been visited yet. If so, return
- Checks to see if the position being iterated over has a 1 or 0. If 1, return.
- Checks to see if the position being iterated over has the maximum x index (in which case you're at the bottom); return true
- Call the function recursively with all four surrounding squares: (0, 1), (1, 0), (0, -1), (-1, 0). If any of the recursive calls return true, return true. Should be as simple as

  ```
  return [
    recuse(x + 1, y),
    recuse(x - 1, y),
    recuse(x, y + 1),
    recuse(x, y - 1),
  ].some(Boolean);
  ```
- To start out the recursion, call the function for all top elements at index 0 in the input array.

There are a number of things you have to do to put it together, but it's a pretty simple algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for this! I'll shoe horn it into my head. This seems useful other similar problems. I feel like I should know how to do this kind of thing by now.

Comment: I am having a little bit of trouble understanding the process you laid out. I wrote a function that gets all of the array incises that have a value of zero and pushes their positions to a new returned array. I know that isn't the instructions. I am trying to get back on track and visualize what you are trying to tell me. Maybe you can work with me and help me take what I made and nudge it in a better direction. I feel like I am on the verge of understanding but need to be pushed. https://jsfiddle.net/k4zqhw8s/1/

Comment: The fiddle code is using a pretty different approach, one that's top-down rather than undirected recursive. For a top down algorithm, keeping track of the found indicies isn't useful, because you're always going from `arr[0]`, then to `arr[1]`, then to `arr[2]`, etc - if all you need is to figure out which indicies have 0s, use the top-down approach without keeping track of prior found nodes.

Comment: You probably want `arr[index].forEach((val, indexInner) => {
    if (val === 0) {
      visited.push([parentIndex, indexInner]);
    }
  })`

Comment: I don't want the top down approach. I am trying to keep my mind from drifting in that direction so-to-speak. I'll write my own pseudo code that revisits your initial approach and post a jsfiddle later. Thanks for working with me on this.

Comment: For explaining the problem would you say that the following sentence summarizes the pattern you are going for:   "Select first item and set the coordinates in an array named "alreadyVisited". if index value is 
zero check the value of all items around it. If item value is 1 do nothing. For all surrounding items that are 0's repeat recursion."

Comment: Sure, that's a starting point. Though, note that you start recursion at *all* top elements, and not just a single one (like `[0][0]`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239968/discussion-between-william-and-certainperformance).